# How to install updates on Progress-4GL programs

Tags: installation, command-line, openedge, progress-4gl

Good afternoon,
In my company, we are regularly doing updates on customers' systems, all Progress-4GL technology. Currently we are doing all this manually, and I'd like to automate this.

The following actions are needed:

- Take a dump (*.df) of the current database
- Upload modifications to the database (*.df files)
- compile *.w and *.p files.

Is there a tool that does all that (together with zipping/unzipping *.w, *.p and *.i files), or do I need to create such a tool myself?

In the latter case, what are the commandline commands for the mentioned actions:

- Take a dump (*.df) of the current database
- Upload modifications to the database (*.df files)
- compile *.w and *.p files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're familiar with ANT, the take a look at the PCT plugin for ANT:

https://github.com/Riverside-Software/pct

This makes is easy to create a delta.df file between the "new" full DF and the current database, e.g.:

```
<PCTDumpIncremental destFile="temp/delta.df" dlcHome="${dlc}" 
   debugLevel="2" activeIndexes="0" removeEmptyDFFile="true" msgBufferSize="${Mm}" >
    
    <SourceDB dbname="temp/ref-SmartDB" singleUser="true" />
    <TargetDB dbname="${smartdb}" dbDir="${smartdbdir}" singleUser="${smartdbsingleuser}"/>
</PCTDumpIncremental>
```

and then load the delta.df into the current application DB:

```
<PCTLoadSchema srcFile="temp/delta.df" dlcHome="${dlc}" onlineChanges="true" callbackClass="rssw.pct.AbstractLoadCallback" msgBufferSize="${Mm}"  commitWhenErrors="false">
    <DBConnectionSet refid="smartdbset" />
</PCTLoadSchema>
```

and then compile the application:

```
<PCTCompile destDir="${installroot}" graphicalMode="true" dlcHome="${dlc}"
    md5="true" minSize="false" cpinternal="${cpinternal}" cpColl="${cpcoll}" cpstream="${cpstream}" 
    compileUnderscore="true" inputchars="32000" baseDir="${installroot}"
    token="4000" progPerc="10" assemblies="${assemblies}">
    <fileset dir="${installroot}" casesensitive="false">
        <include name="Ccs/**/*.cls"/>
        <include name="Consultingwerk/**/*.cls"/>
        <include name="Consultingwerk/**/*.p"/>
        <include name="Consultingwerk/**/*.w"/>
        <include name="Setup/**/*.p"/>
        <include name="src/**/*.p"/>
     </fileset>

    <propath>
        <pathelement path="${installroot}/." />
        <pathelement path="${installroot}/src" />
        <pathelement path="${installroot}/Consultingwerk/Studio/ProdictDumpHack/src" />
        <pathelement path="${dlc}/gui/netlib/OpenEdge.Net.pl" />                
    </propath>
    <DBConnectionSet refid="smartdbset" />
</PCTCompile>
```

ANT and PCT are included in OpenEdge from 11.7 on. Since you're on 11.6, you'll have to bring your own ANT and PCT.

Comment: I'm not familiar with ANT (yet), but those PCT look like a good way of working (and a good reason to upgrade to at leat release 11.7).

Comment: Upgrading to a supported release is always good! But PCT works well with 11.6